# Why is my client IP returned as ::1 on xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, ip

I am trying to get the client IP in order to compare it to some ranges, but I am failing at the first step: determining the IP address of the user.

I use the following code:

```
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
echo $ip;
```

But I get this as result: `::1`

I am using XAMPP.

How can I get my real IP and why would XAMPP output my internal network IP and not my real IP or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You are accessing the site via local network - there is no round trip via you ISP, so no external ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is the `localhost` in IPv6. Your test box is using IPv6 to connect to localhost.

You can either explicitly use `127.0.0.1` or configure `/etc/hosts` to use `127.0.0.1` for `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

:1 stands for localhost / 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your ipadress in xampp my ipadress is 192.168.1.3

```
<?php

$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
$ip1 = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
$ip2 = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
$ip3 = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
$ip4 = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
$ip5 = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');


echo "HTTP_CLIENT_IP  : ".$ip."</br>";
echo "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR : ".$ip1."</br>";
echo "HTTP_X_FORWARDED : ".$ip2."</br>";
echo "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR  : ".$ip3."</br>";
echo "HTTP_FORWARDED  : ".$ip4."</br>";
echo "REMOTE_ADDR : ".$ip5."</br>";

?>
```

Comment: still outputs `::1`, was looking for the solution where I can use SERVER_ADDR or some vairable to be set as the url , which would work with both of my dev env ( windows /linux)