# PHP Session Cookie Not Stored in XAMPP

Tags: php, file, session

For some reason the php session cookie file is not being stored on XAMPP in the default tmp directory, and I ran a search of the entire XAMPP for the session_id() and there are no results. Any ideas??

There is one file "sess_6mkb82rg31nmgjmf7i3ee7mjif" but it doesn't appear to be in the same format as a client-side cookie and is not the correct session id. The correct one is statically across multiple page loads "u8c6ldb8dcpddr55d542vodtpr". There are database queries coded into the file I found. I'm not sure what this may be. However it is in the correct directory where sessions are stored because there is a file called why.tmp and it says do not delete the session files.

What I am trying to do is find the session file and copy the contents to a new file with a new id because I've seen that creating a new id every page load is recommended on stackoverflow to reduce the risks of hacks by session fixation.

I am sure that the code doesn't change the session id after I get it from the virtual server because I am only at the point of getting the contents of the old session file so far.

I have built a successfully running framework that has no problems with sessions other than me finding the session file. It must be stored outside of the XAMPP directory or the data is saved within another file.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't need to do that manually. you can use [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) for that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you don't need to manually modify temp files to assign a visitor a new session... What you're doing seems to be very hacky.

Comment: Warning: Current session_regenerate_id does not handle unstable network well. e.g. Mobile and WiFi network. Therefore, you may experience lost session by calling session_regenerate_id.

Comment: That is directly from php manual

Comment: Scrolled down to examples and found a solution. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning near the top of session_regenerate_id() in the php manual that states that on unstable networks, you may loose the session data. But for no apparent reason I decided to go back and look at the examples anyways and there is an example solution to this problem under the following heading in the manual:

Example #2 Avoiding lost session by session_regenerate_id()

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is normal for simulated services like Xampp and others users like me is currently having that problem if do you need more information Check de [OficialXamppForum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=82992) that talks about to create a *$_COOKIE* (for any propourse) after to use the method *setcookie($NameCookie,$Content,time()+$Seconds);* the LocalServer correctly assign the Cookie, but!, later if I going to refresh the page pressing F5, the cookie will be erased, now, I recommend you press the button (i) near the link in your browser and check if the info and expiration date are correctly like this image:

[image: See Cookies PHP]

Later, if any information is correctly trust me the cookie was set correctly, that "XamppIssue" is not happen only on PHP-Cookies, also occur with the method `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'` that is assumed to allows to read the private ip user ex: (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX), but! in XamppServer was loaded like this "::1::" or "1" or "::1" or ":1:" or ":1" and can check this discussion [here in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076345/why-is-my-client-ip-returned-as-1-on-xampp) when the people says that the method was applied correctly but because is a LocalHost has those limitations at time to executing PHP .

Finally if you want to check DEFINITELY!! if your PHP  runs correctly use a host like 000WebHost or Azure to discard any problems.

Have a nice day :D :D .